# Build shared libraries in ATLAS

Tags: installation, shared-libraries, lapack, atlas

I've read the entire ATLAS installation guide, and it says all you need to build shared (.so) libraries is to pass the `--shared` flag to the configure script. However, when I build, the only `.so` files that appear in my `lib` folder are `libsatlas.so` and `libtatlas.so`, though the guide says that there should be six others:

```
libatlas.so, libcblas.so, libf77blas.so, liblapack.so, libptcblas.so, libptf77blas.so
```

After installation some of the tests fail because these libraries are missing. Furthermore, FFPACK wants these libraries during installation.

Has anyone encountered this? What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: How to pass the --shared flag to the configure script?

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, it's a lot more complex than that, see our EasyBuild implementation of the ATLAS build procedure at https://github.com/hpcugent/easybuild-easyblocks/blob/master/easybuild/easyblocks/a/atlas.py .

We needed to:

- enable the -fPIC compiler option
- run 'make shared cshared ptshared cptshared' in the 'lib' directory

We're not even using --shared for configure, probably because it doesn't do much.

If you want to build ATLAS (and whatever you will be linking it with) without headaches, look into EasyBuild.

(disclaimer: I'm a developer for EasyBuild)

Comment: How to enable the -fPIC compiler option?

Comment: @郭同jet_专心 see https://github.com/hpcugent/easybuild-easyblocks/blob/c2a9fe50fcdb77708f47eb1edfa378a8a848808d/easybuild/easyblocks/a/atlas.py#L123

Basically, you configure ATLAS with ``-Fa alg -fPIC``

Comment: It would be great if the _Easy_Build thing was actually _easy_ to install. Downloaded your bootstrapping script, even watched the video (never understood why people make you skip back and forth through a non-text-based format to find text-based instructions) but still can't get the script to work. Very frustrating experience, sorry to say.

Comment: @RainerVerteidiger Sorry to hear it didn't work out for you... Please consider reporting the problem(s) you ran into at https://github.com/easybuilders/easybuild-framework/issues, and hopefully we can sort them out.

Answer (score 0):

[First if you have incorrectly specified the --force-tids flag for configure then the parallel libs won't build. To check this you can run make ptcheck](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3577908&group_id=23725&atid=379483). I have question regarding the specification of this flag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525852/determining-the-independent-cpus-specified-with-affinity-ids-for-building-at)

Then if I examine my resulting ATLAS Makefile it says " ... only when atlas is built to one lib" and indeed only two "fat" libs are constructed: libsatlas.so and libtatlas.so.

I quess you can either link FFPACK against those libs or change the resulting ATLAS Makefile to contain the targets you need (Which won't be too hard since the static libs are available).

Answer (score -1):

I had to manually create links to the .so.3 files.
So the versioned library files existed, but not the files the cmake was looking for.

Running

```
 sudo ln -s libatlas.so.3 libatlas.so
 sudo ln -s libcblas.so.3 libcblas.so
 sudo ln -s liblapack_atlas.so.3
```

(I didn't build the cblas, atlas or lapack but installed them with apt-get. Wondering why the links were not automatically created).

Comment: Question is about "building" ATLAS from source, not installing it with a package manager.